# Swift - enum conformance return allCases of different types

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I got `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions` I know that's because the compiler can't resolve the type, what's can make it more simple for the compiler?

Also, always looking to do better, is there a better approach to assign a value to a data model who shares the same protocol conformance?

```
  protocol RelationshipType:CaseIterable {
        
        associatedtype relationShip
    }
```

---

```
enum RomanticRelationType:String, RelationshipType {
       
    
        case couple, married, engaged
        
        var title: String {
            
            switch self {
            case .couple:
                return "Couple"
            case .married:
                return "Married"
            case .engaged:
                return "Engaged"
            }
        }
        var priority: Int {
            switch self {
            case .couple:
                return 3
            case .engaged:
                return 2
            case .married:
                return 1
            }
        }
        
  }
```

---

```
extension RomanticRelationType {
    typealias relationShip = RomanticRelationType
    
    static var allCases: [RomanticRelationType] {
        return [.couple, .married, .engaged]
    }
}
```

---

```
var relationships:any RelationshipType {
    
    switch selectedRelationType {
    case .personal:
        return PersonalRelationType.allCases as! (any RelationshipType)
    case .professional:
        return ProfessionalRelationType.allCases as! (any RelationshipType)
    case .romantic:
        return RomanticRelationType.allCases as! (any RelationshipType)
    }

    
}
```

---

```
            Picker("Type", selection: $relationsVM.selectedRelation.relationship) {
                ForEach(relationsVM.relationships, id: \.self) { relationType in
                    Text(relationType.title)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The title is the subject. The error appears in the first Vstack where the Picker is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is this (and the related lines):

```
    return PersonalRelationType.allCases as! (any RelationshipType)
```

This is invalid. `[RomanticRelationType]` does not conform to `RelationshipType`. An array is not the same thing as an element. I believe you meant this:

```
var relationships:[any RelationshipType] {
    switch selectedRelationType {
    case .personal:
        return PersonalRelationType.allCases
    case .professional:
        return ProfessionalRelationType.allCases
    case .romantic:
        return RomanticRelationType.allCases 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, correct. I still get the same error and don't understand why, there is nothing to break up the expression intro distance sub-expressions..

Comment: Remove terms until it becomes clearer. Replace each piece with a simpler literal. (In this above example, you would replace the `switch` with `return []`. If that works, you would make each case return `[]`, and if that worked, you'd add back on case leg at at time to see which is the cause.